# Botón para borrar registros no ejecuta ninguna acción PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla que muestra todos los registros de una base de datos ( esto funciona bien ), al final de la tabla añado un botón para borrar el registro en caso de que el administrador quiera, esta es mi tabla:

```
<?php 
        while($mostrar=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
      echo "<tbody>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[0]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[3]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[4]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[5]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[6]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[19]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[2]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[12]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[13]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[1]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[7]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[8]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[9]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[14]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[10]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[11]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[15]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[17]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[20]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$mostrar[21]."</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='submit' value='borrar' onclick = 'location='delete.php?nombre=".$mostrar[0]."/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";

}
?>
```

Y aquí añado la página que ejecuta la sentencia de borrar (delete.php):

```
<?php
$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('clientes') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
$url = "";
$sql = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE Nombre = $nombre"; 

if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    mysqli_close($link);
    header('Location: mostrar.php');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Error borrando al usuario";
}
?>
```

No se si el error está al pasar el dato nombre en el botón o es que no ejecuta bien la sentencia al no recibir el nombre, simplemente no hace nada.

Comment: añade el error que te sale

Comment: @AlfredoPaz no muestra ninguno, por eso no se que hacer, simplemente no pasa nada

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Al parecer tienes problemas al momento de concatenar los valores al botón quizá debería tener la siguiente estructura para escapar las comillas *(elimine el type ya que no veo necesario)*. independientemente de esto , siempre puede inspeccionar el elemento para saber que valores renderiza.

```
echo "<td><input 
value='borrar' 
onclick =\"location.href='delete.php?nombre=".$mostrar[0]."' \"/></td>";
```

Aunque si hará una re dirección podría haber empleado un `<a>` directamente.

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?nombre=". $mostrar[0]."'>Eliminar</td>";
```

Además está mezclando dos extensiones `MySQL` Y `MySQLi`.En la conexión usa `mysql`  y al ejecutar la consulta `mysqli_query`  es otra extensión lo mismo para el cierre de la conexión , *(recomiendo hacer todo con una sola de preferencia MySQLiy utilizando sentencias preparadas como en la parte final de mi respuesta )* .Si usa la primera y vuelvo a reiterar funcionará pero no lo recomiendo. *(la ejecución de la consulta podría quedar así)*

```
if(mysql_query($consulta)){
  header('Location: mostrar.php');
}
```

> Por lo demás está utilizando una Extensión deprecated lo cuál es
>   incorrecto , además su código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de
>   [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Su código PHP, empleando la extensión MySQLi y sentencias preparadas podría tener este formato.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "clientes");
$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM clientes WHERE Nombre = ?")) {
    //bind del valor por GET a la consulta 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $nombre);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        header('Location: mostrar.php'); 
    }
    else echo "Error borrando al usuario";
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: en la parte de conexion, antes de acceder a estas páginas tengo todo cifrado para que a esto solo puedan acceder los admins. PD: yo intenté hacer todo en Mysqli, pero la version con la que me encontre era anterior, no depende de mi

Comment: Despues de hacer la respuesta mediante link ahora si me salta un error en el delete php: `PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/localhost/delete.php on line 8`

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez gracias , efectivamente se me olvidó ese detalle . en la conexión usa `mysql`  y al ejecutar la consulta `mysqli_query`  es otra extensión , _(recomiendo hacer todo con una sola de preferencia MySQLi )_

Comment: Cuando uso `$query = 'DELETE FROM clientes WHERE Nombre = $nombre';` y `mysql_query(&query)` salta el siguiente error: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: `&`  ? amigo para una variable se usa `$query`   , vuelvo a reiterar su código es muy confuso al intentar fusionar dos extensiones ... use una sola  por favor para el error del botón y la redirección mi respuesta soluciona ese detalle.

Comment: Perdon, me equivoque al escribir el comentario, si pudieras explicarme porque el interrogante en la sentencia DELETE FROM

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez son sentencias preparadas , y se emplean marcadores para pasar valores , [revise la documentación de bind_param y entenderá un poco más](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) una respuesta más extensa escapa de la pregunta principal lo mismo los comentarios :) Saludos

Comment: Perfecto, funciona con mysqli, muchas gracias por todo